# Why is the SARIMAX forecast shifted into the training set?

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima

I am trying to forecast daily electricity consumption using SARIMAX. However, it appears to me, that the forecasted series is shifted. Does anyone know, how this can happen?

```
total_normalized
            Consumption  Temperature   Radiation  weekly first difference
DATUM                                                                    
2018-01-08     7532.644     1.073611  303.800000                 1666.145
2018-01-09     7643.685     2.169633  189.000000                  848.669
2018-01-10     7471.557     6.381944  113.800000                  470.387
2018-01-11     7419.188     5.160139  190.866667                  522.394
2018-01-12     7441.262     4.401250   95.800000                  637.488
```

I have split my data set into:

```
train=total_normalized.iloc[:len(total_normalized)-30] 
test=total_normalized.iloc[len(total_normalized)-30:]
```

And from here the series/array for the endogenous and exogenous variables are created

```
endog_train_diff=train['weekly first difference']
 endog_test_diff=test['weekly first difference']
exog_train=train[['Temperature','Radiation']].to_numpy() 
exog_test=test[['Temperature','Radiation']].to_numpy()
```

However, while the last index of the train set is 2020-08-01 and the first index of the test set is 2020-08-02, the first forecasted consumption is however 2020-07-31. I noticed this while debugging.

```
model=sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(endog_train_diff,exog=exog_train,order=(1,1,5),seasonal_order=(0,1,1,7),
trend='ct',enforce_stationarity=False,enforce_invertibility=False) 
results=model.fit(disp=False) 
forecast = results.forecast(steps=30,exog=exog_test)
```

[image: Image of the shifted forecast wrt to the original values]
In this way, the exogenuous values of the test set can not be matched with the correct date.
I assume, that this also has influence on the forecast performance.

Is this a known problem, or is there something I have missed in my code?

Comment: You may need to clarify your question - you say that the forecasts start on July 31, but then in your graph, the first forecast is on August 2.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made a mistake when plotting. I have updated the figure.

Comment: I can't replicate this result, so it seems likely that you'll need to post a full example including data (which you can simulate if you can't share the original dataset) that shows the problem.